# Export data from Big Query table to GCS across projects - java API

Tags: java, google-bigquery

I'm trying to export data from a Big Query table to GCS by Java API.
The Big Query table is the ProjectA while the GCS bucket in ProjectB and I have 2 different accounts (keys) to access them.
It seems there is no way in JobConfigurationExtractor object to specify  destination credentials and the project details, just for Big Query object/table.
Is there a way to overcome this limitation? Anyone experiencing similar issues?

Snippet code

```
JobConfigurationExtract extract =
    new JobConfigurationExtract().setSourceTable(table).setDestinationUri(cloudStoragePath);

return bigquery
    .jobs()
    .insert(
        table.getProjectId(),
        new Job().setConfiguration(new JobConfiguration().setExtract(extract)))
    .execute();
```

}

Thanks!